# change JTokenType property of JToken object

Tags: c#, json

I want to write a function (c#) that get JToken as parameter
and change his Type from JTokenType.Date to JTokenType.String (it's a readonly property so i cant do it)

something like:

```
if(jTokenObject.Type == JTokenType.Date)
{
\\code here...
}
```

Comment: What's to stop you constructing a new one?

Comment: how do i construct new one with the same values but only JTokenType.String ?

Comment: create a new JObject with the desired structure and map it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i've found a way by myself xd

```
private static string JTokenToString(JToken jtoken)
{
     var JTokenReader = new JTokenReader(jtoken);

     return JTokenReader.ReadAsString();
}
```